# Dismiss push notification banner

Tags: objective-c, swift, push-notification, notifications

How to remove from the Lock screen the Notification banner, like  in Telegram messenger? 
Behavior:

- The User receives a message in chat.
- User receives a push notification on IPhone and Mac.
- The user reads the message with a Mac.
- Banner notifications are automatically deleted from lock screen iphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear all push notifications only from app:

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```